# why nextButton() function is not running?

Tags: javascript

I'm still newbie and trying to make a simple website, one of my feature is calendar.

why is my function nextbutton() is not running?

I also need some critics where and what should i change in coding. thank you so much!

```
    function calendar(){    
        date = new Date();
        month = date.getMonth();
        year = date.getFullYear();
        var dayOfweek = date.getDay();      
        var day = date.getDate();
        var nameOftheMonth = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];
        var nameOftheDays = ["SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"];
        var nextMonth = month+1;
        var prevMonth = month-1;
        var numberOfDays = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay();
        var TotalNumOfDays = new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();
        var num2 = numberOfDays+1;
        var num = 1;
        var content = "";

        content += "<button><----</button><div>" + nameOftheMonth[month] + " " + year + "</div><button>----></button>"; 

        content += "<br/><table><tr>";                  
        for (count=0;count <= nameOftheDays.length-1; count++){

            content += "<td>" + nameOftheDays[count] + "</td>"; 

            if(count === nameOftheDays.length-1){
                content += "</tr><tr>";
            }
        }           
        while (numberOfDays > 0) {  
                content += "<td></td>";
                numberOfDays--;
        }

        while (num <= TotalNumOfDays){
            content += "<td>" + num + "</td>";
            if (num2 > 6) {
                num2 = 0;
                content += "</tr><tr>"
            }
            num2++;
            num++;              
        }   

        document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = content;
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute("id", "prevbutton");
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute("onclick", "prevButton()");     
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1].setAttribute("id", "nextButton");
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1].setAttribute("onclick", "nextButton()");
        document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].setAttribute("id", "dateToday");

    }
    function nextButton(){
        if(month != null){
            month = month++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please create a working copy of it?

Comment: Without the full code (or a verifiable sample) it would be difficult to tell the first thing going wrong. I can say you should use `addEventListener('click', nextButton)` instead of `setAttribute`. If you want a code review, this might also be relevant http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @brk what do you mean? you want source code js and html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="calendar"></div>

<script language="JavaScript">      
var month=-1;
 function calendar(){  
        date = new Date();
        if(month===-1){
        month =date.getMonth();
        }
        year = date.getFullYear();
        var dayOfweek = date.getDay();      
        var day = date.getDate();
        var nameOftheMonth = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];
        var nameOftheDays = ["SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"];
        var nextMonth = month+1;
        var prevMonth = month-1;
        var numberOfDays = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay();
        var TotalNumOfDays = new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();
        var num2 = numberOfDays+1;
        var num = 1;
        var content = "";

        content += "<button><----</button><div>" + nameOftheMonth[month] + " " + year + "</div><button>----></button>"; 

        content += "<br/><table><tr>";                  
        for (count=0;count <= nameOftheDays.length-1; count++){

            content += "<td>" + nameOftheDays[count] + "</td>"; 

            if(count === nameOftheDays.length-1){
                content += "</tr><tr>";
            }
        }           
        while (numberOfDays > 0) {  
                content += "<td></td>";
                numberOfDays--;
        }

        while (num <= TotalNumOfDays){
            content += "<td>" + num + "</td>";
            if (num2 > 6) {
                num2 = 0;
                content += "</tr><tr>"
            }
            num2++;
            num++;              
        }   
        document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = content;
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute("id", "prevbutton");
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute("onclick", "prevButton()");     
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1].setAttribute("id", "nextButton");
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1].setAttribute("onclick", "nextButton()");
        document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].setAttribute("id", "dateToday");

    }
    function nextButton(){
        if(month != null){
document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML ="";
            month++;
            calendar()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you should call calendar() function on load

Comment: thank you this works for me although i got question why its empty document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML =""; ??

Comment: also i created function prevButton(){
   if(month != null){
    document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = "";
    month--;
    calendar()
   }
  }

why is it looping? when i click after january it goes march again

Comment: Okay i get it now. U use empty innerhtml so when i change month it will add+1, and it will rerun calendar function. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. I pulled the vars out of the calendar() function, and set your nextButton() function (which works, by the way, just do a console.log to see) to call the calendar function every time. Also, to increment, just do var++

```js
 var date = new Date();
 var month = date.getMonth();
 var year = date.getFullYear();
   
 function calendar(month) {
   
   var dayOfweek = date.getDay();
   var day = date.getDate();
   var nameOftheMonth = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];
   var nameOftheDays = ["SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"];
   var nextMonth = month + 1;
   var prevMonth = month - 1;
   var numberOfDays = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay();
   var TotalNumOfDays = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
   var num2 = numberOfDays + 1;
   var num = 1;
   var content = "";
   content += "<button><----</button><div>" + nameOftheMonth[month] + " " + year + "</div><button>----></button>";
   content += "<br/><table><tr>";
    
   for (count = 0; count <= nameOftheDays.length - 1; count++) {
    content += "<td>" + nameOftheDays[count] + "</td>";
    if (count === nameOftheDays.length - 1) {
     content += "</tr><tr>";
    }
   }
   while (numberOfDays > 0) {
    content += "<td></td>";
    numberOfDays--;
   }
   while (num <= TotalNumOfDays) {
    content += "<td>" + num + "</td>";
    if (num2 > 6) {
     num2 = 0;
     content += "</tr><tr>"
    }
    num2++;
    num++;
   }
   document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = content;
   document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute("id", "prevbutton");
   document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute("onclick", "prevButton()");
   document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1].setAttribute("id", "nextButton");
   document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1].setAttribute("onclick", "nextButton()");
   document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].setAttribute("id", "dateToday");
  }

  function nextButton() {

   if (month != null) {
    console.log(month);
    month++;
    calendar(month);
   }
  }
```

```html
    <body onload="calendar(month)">
         
    <div id="calendar">
          
    </div>
    <div id="today">
    </div>
 
 </body>
```

Comment: Apparently I need to get the hang of this code editor thing.

Comment: so i will use innerHTML instead of console.log?

Comment: the console.log was just to show you that the month variable was incrementing - technically you don't need to do anything other than increment and call the calendar() function again. You don't even need to worry about innerHTML in nextButton function, because it is replaced by the contents of the variable "content" right here:

document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = content;

Answer (score 0):

**nextButton** click is not working because it is a dynamically created element.

So we need to attach the click listeners on newly created DOM elements using, `addEventListener`.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1].addEventListener('click', yourFunction);
```

I have used simple JS prototyping to modify the code slightly, this way you can add more methods to your calendar and have multiple instances of it.

```js
 function Calendar(month,date,year) { 
        this.month = month, this.date = date, this.year = year;
         this.nameOftheMonth = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];
         this.nameOftheDays = ["SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"];
          
    }
    
    Calendar.prototype.init = function() { 
          this.date = new Date();
          this.month = this.date.getMonth();
          this.year = this.date.getFullYear(); 
          this.render();
        }
        
    Calendar.prototype.render = function() {
          var dayOfweek = this.date.getDay();      
          var day = this.date.getDate();
        
          var nextMonth = this.month+1;
          var prevMonth = this.month-1;
          var numberOfDays = new Date(this.year, this.month, 1).getDay();
          var TotalNumOfDays = new Date(this.year, this.month+1, 0).getDate();
          var num2 = numberOfDays+1;
          var num = 1;
          var content = "";

          content += "<button><----</button><div>" + this.nameOftheMonth[this.month] + " " + this.year + "</div><button>----></button>"; 

          content += "<br/><table><tr>";                  
        for (count=0;count <= this.nameOftheDays.length-1; count++){

          content += "<td>" + this.nameOftheDays[count] + "</td>"; 

          if(count === this.nameOftheDays.length-1){
              content += "</tr><tr>";
          }
        }           
        while (numberOfDays > 0) {  
                content += "<td></td>";
                numberOfDays--;
        }

        while (num <= TotalNumOfDays){
            content += "<td>" + num + "</td>";
            if (num2 > 6) {
                num2 = 0;
                content += "</tr><tr>"
            }
            num2++;
            num++;              
        }   

        document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = content;
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute("id", "prevbutton");    
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1].setAttribute("id", "nextButton");
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener('click', (function() {
          this.prevButton();
        }).bind(this));
        
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1].addEventListener('click', (function() {
          this.nextButton();
        }).bind(this));
        
        document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].setAttribute("id", "dateToday");
        }    

    Calendar.prototype.nextButton = function(){
        if(this.month !== null){
            this.month += 1;
            this.render();
        }
    }
    
    Calendar.prototype.prevButton = function(){
        if(this.month !== null){
            this.month -= 1;
            this.render();
        }
    }
    
    var c =new Calendar();
    c.init();
```

```html
<div id="calendar">

</div>
```

Comment: thank you i somehow get it know. i tried this one earlier but doesnt work but the way you code somehow confusing im in basic javascript